# How to track how long it takes to do something in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, timing, procedure

Basically I'm doing this in a procedure:

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR r_cursor is SELECT * from imp_exp.results where code = 8223558 FOR  UPDATE OF c_timestamp;

 BEGIN

 FOR idx IN r_cursor LOOP
   --dbms_output.put_line(idx.sample_code);
   update imp_exp.results set c_timestamp = TO_DATE('10-MAY-99', 'DD-MON=YY')    
WHERE CURRENT OF r_cursor;

END LOOP;

END;
```

How can I display how long this took? Thanks!

Comment: Note that you've got a typo in your code-- the format mask should be 'DD-MON-YY' with a dash not 'DD-MON=YY' with an equals sign.

Comment: ahh thanks. hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set timing on
begin
  call_your_procedure;
end;
```

This will produce:

```
anonymous block completed
Elapsed: 00:00:05.524
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also opt to use [`DBMS_UTILITY.get_time`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i1002765)

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR r_cursor IS
      SELECT *
      FROM   imp_exp.results
      WHERE  code = 8223558
      FOR UPDATE OF c_timestamp;
    v_start_time NUMBER;
    v_end_time   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_start_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;

    FOR idx IN r_cursor LOOP
        --dbms_output.put_line(idx.sample_code);
        UPDATE imp_exp.results
        SET    c_timestamp = To_date('10-MAY-99', 'DD-MON=YY')
        WHERE  CURRENT OF r_cursor;
    END LOOP;

    v_end_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;

    dbms_output.Put_line('Elapsed time in seconds: '
                         || (v_end_time - v_start_time ) / 100);
END;
```